# Split record from one column to two column in MysQL or PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem to split data from attendance machine. The data source after export from it like this:

```
id name  att
1  John  01/04/2015   7:59:00
1  John  01/04/2015  17:44:00
1  John  02/04/2015   7:50:00
1  John  02/04/2015  18:14
```

Where record (in and out) from fingerprint time save in one column. And I want to split the data to be like this:

```
id name  in                  out
1  John  01/04/2015 7:59:00  01/04/2015 17:44:00
1  John  02/04/2015 7:50:00  02/04/2015 18:14:00
```

How to split those record into 2 column in MySQL or PHP (maybe)? Thank you.

Comment: Where is the code you have tried?

Comment: is there only ever one in/out on a given day?

Comment: order the data by employee and date time, pick the first entry as in , the second entry as out, it can be done using self join or window function.

Comment: there are no window functions mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is only one in/out per day, it's as simple as self-joining on the date and greater time.

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.att as `in`, t2.att as `out`
  from table1 t1
    inner join table1 t2
      on date(t1.att) = date(t2.att) and t1.id = t2.id
        and t2.att > t1.att
```

[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99ab8/7)

If you want to create a brand new table with this data, so you can get rid of the import, you just need to use this query as the input to `create table`, like so:

```
create table new_table
  as
    select t1.id, t1.name, t1.att as `in`, t2.att as `out`
      from table1 t1
        inner join table1 t2
          on date(t1.att) = date(t2.att) and t1.id = t2.id
            and t2.att > t1.att
```

Comment: Thank you, it's work. I noticed that my att column is still in local format date, so I convert it first in MS Excell into MySQL date time then with MySQLtoExcell tool import to MySQL table then run the query.

Comment: yeah timezones and formats can be quite the pain :(

Comment: Yes, I try to aware. But I have one problem, if a user forgot to use fingerprint where he out (only in recorded and out is null), the query result not display user who only one time present. Any suggestion sir? Thank you.

Comment: change `inner join` to `left join`

Answer (score -1):

You could try this one.

```
        SELECT a.userID,a.name,min(a.att)as `in`,max(a.att) as `out`
        FROM
            (
                SELECT userID,name,str_to_date(att,'%m/%d/%Y%T') as att,str_to_date(att,'%m/%d/%Y') as attd
                FROM attendance
            ) as a
        GROUP BY a.userID,a.attd
```

Comment: upvotes for a query that wont work against the schema provided in the question? makes sense.